# Restler custom URL routing not working

Tags: restler

In my REST API I have Work associated with an Order, so using Restler (3.0.0-RC6) I created this method:

```php
class Orders {
    /**
     * Get completed work for order
     *
     * @param int $id The SQL identifier of the order
     *
     * @return array {@type Work}
     *
     * @url GET orders/{id}/works
     */
     function getCompletedWork($id) {
```

So now I go to my url and enter `..../index.php/orders/1/works` and I get back a 404 from `Routes.php:436 at route stage`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom routes are also mapped along with the name of the class unless we provide an empty string as the second parameter while adding the Api class

```
$r->addAPIClass('Orders','');
```

So your example above is actually mapped to `orders/orders/{id}/works`. You can fix with

```
class Orders {
    /**
     * Get completed work for order
     *
     * @param int $id The SQL identifier of the order
     *
     * @return array {@type Work}
     *
     * @url GET {id}/works
     */
     function getCompletedWork($id) {
```